# ios badge not changing when application in inactive State in Push Notifiaction

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, badge

I want to change badge of my application when my application is in inactive state. When my application is in active state The badge is incrementing by 1 by

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:    (NSDictionary *)userInfo 
{    
    NSInteger badgeNumber = [application applicationIconBadgeNumber];

    [application setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:++badgeNumber];   
    NSInteger badgeNumber = [application applicationIconBadgeNumber];

    [application setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:++badgeNumber];
}
```

But when my application is in the inactive state. I read that the operating system automatically give the badge  send in the payload.
Here is my payload:

```
{
    "aps": {
        "alert": "You have an image to view",
        "sound": "default",
        "badge": 2
    }
}
```

But the badge is not changing. Can any one help me with this.

Comment: so you receive the alert notification but the badge doesn't change? ...your code is right. Other info that you can give us?

Comment: As far I know it is the operating system who changes the badge automatically.But it is not changing.I tried on different divices but it didn't work.